# How do I get customer attribute using an observer

Tags: event-observer, magento-1

I am using this event in the customer create account page: `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_create`

I am trying to load a customer attribute here and I want to change its value.
I tried smth like this:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getAttributeText('customer_attribute_code');
```

But it is null. Is there a way to load a customer attribute and change its value using an observer ? thx

Comment: Try loading the value as below:
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

$controller->getRequest()->getPostValue();

Comment: I got this: Fatal Error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::getPostValue()

Comment: i guess you should be using event as controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost

Comment: should i use an event before the page load ? cuz i want to change a customer attribute value, so when the user clicks on the registration page will get the customer attribute value what i set in the observer

Comment: Its a custom customer attribute, which was added . It is not relevant which one :)

Comment: I mean to say whether that attribute will have predefined values that you would want to change or you want to fill those attribute..

Comment: I want to filter my attribute after a condition and load it accordingly to that condition in the frontend, inthe customer registration page

Comment: but I first, I want to change my attribute , like by default myattribute = 1 , I want to change it in the observer to be 2 and than display it in the frontend